# Am I supposed to use Objects or ViewModels for MVC or both?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning MVC. I have an application that I developed using webforms that I'm porting over, but I've hit a bit of a *snag*.

I'm using the Entity Framework as well.

Currently, my models represent database tables. Generally my controller will grab the data from the table and create a view model that will be passed to the view.

Where I'm a bit confused is when I need to make some transformations based on the model data and pass it to the view I'm not sure where that transformation takes place.

In the webforms application I would have a class where I would create new objects from and then all of the transformations would happen there. A good example would be a `User`; the database would store first and last name, and the object would have a public property for `FullName` that would get set in the constructor.

I've read some conflicting discussions on Thin Controllers/Fat Models, and vice-versa. I'm just a little confused. Thin controllers and fat models seems to be the recommended way according to the Microsoft docs, but they don't really give real world examples of doing so.

So with an example:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
}

public class UserController : Controller {
{
    protected readonly DBContext _context;
    public UserController(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IactionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var _user = _context.Users.Single(u => u.id == id);

        UserViewModel _viewModel = new UserViewModel
        {
            FirstName = _user.FName,
            LastName = _user.LName,
            FullName = ""
        };

        return View(_viewModel)

    }

}
```

If the above isn't perfect, forgive me - I just wrote it up for a quick example. It's not intended to be flawless code.

For Fullname, where would I put logic that would give me that information. Now, I realize that in *this very simple* example, I could easily get the full name right there. But let's just pretend that it's a much more complex operation than concatenating two strings. Where would I place a `GetFullName` method?

Would I have a method in my model? Would I instead create a `User` class and pass the returned model data? What about having a separate class library? If either of the latter, would I pass `User` objects to my view model or would I set view model properties from the `User` object that was created?

Comment: You could write extension methods if you dont want your viewmodel to have any methods

Comment: Neither way is inherently wrong - an argument can be made that a controller should map, or that the viewmodel could have a constructor that takes the models it needs.  The most important thing is to stay consistent with your layers - pick either way and keep it consistent across your application.

Comment: ViewModels are what the name implies. Models for specific *views*. They aren't domain entities or DTOs. If a method makes sense for a *view's model*, a good place to put it is in the ViewModel. Validations, notifications, calculated properties etc. are all good candidates. A  mortgage calculator on the other hand would be a *bad* candidate - that's a business functionality

Comment: I had to look up extension methods. I feel like this would be a good option in some instances. Would extension methods be stored in a top level directory? Seems like they're essentially static helper methods.

Comment: @gin93r there's nothing wrong with putting methods in the ViewModel, if they only deal with the *viewmodel*. You'll have to be more specific

Comment: @gin93r `remember, when designing your #WebAPI, your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model` https://twitter.com/mamund/status/767212233759657984

Comment: @gin93r Extension methods are just one idea.  I dont know much about your needs/requirements but there is not anything wrong with a view model having some light view related logic.  As others said, a view model shouldnt be some crazy class with a ton of logic and data I/O.  It sounds like you just want to concatenate some strings together though, thats more than reasonable to have in a view model

Comment: @maccettura Well - my needs are more complex than concatenating some strings, I was just using that as an example. A more realistic example is that I'm given a string and I need to parse that string and return something else. It's common enough that I wouldn't want to put it into each view model, so I think an extension method would be good in that case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. In some instances of my application I have transformations that would only be used in the views, and in others I have transformations that should be more of a property.

As I mentioned in Greg's answer, I think realizing that I should separate my Entity models and Object models helps a lot. It just feels so much different than having a class library where I just create new Objects from database data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework often correlates a representation of the business from a relational data implementation.  This approach is ideal for a clean representation of the business model's.  But within a web page that direct representation often doesn't translate or play well within the application structure.

They end up usually implementing a pattern called model-view-view-model (MVVM).  Basically, a transformation of a single or multiple entities into a single object to be placed within the view as a model.  This transformation solves an abundance of issues, example.

```
public class UserModel
{
     private readonly UserEntity user;

     public UserModel(UserEntity user) => this.user = user;

     public string Name => $"{user.First} {user.Last}";
}
```

The entity and database reflect a users name separated, first and last.  But placing the entity into another structure, allows you to build a representative model to adhere to the view.  Obviously a simple example, but the approach is often utilized for a more transparent representation since the view and database may not directly coincide with each other exactly.

So now your controller would do something along these lines.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
     public IActionResult Index(int id) => View(new UserModel(new UserService().GetUserInformation(id)));
}
```

I finished answering, what I'm trying to say with an example a comment expresses quite well.

> ViewModels are what the name implies. Models for specific views. They
>   aren't domain entities or DTOs. If a method makes sense for a view's
>   model, a good place to put it is in the ViewModel. Validations,
>   notifications, calculated properties etc. are all good candidates. A
>   mortgage calculator on the other hand would be a bad candidate -
>   that's a business functionality – Panagiotis Kanavos 7 mins ago

Comment: As far as structure is concerned, would I have a `/Entities/UserEntity.cs` and a `/Models/UserModel.cs`? I think this is probably where some of my confusion was. Another comment that Panagiotis Kanavos quoted about data models are not object models.

Comment: Essentially - I create Entity models that represent that database and then create Object models that would do the transformations, etc. My controllers would pass on Object models to the view. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes, your entity is a object / data model where the view would access an object / view model.  Your data model doesn't always translate into a view model, so you translate a data model to a valid view model.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm understanding this now.

Comment: @gin93r Data Model is a data representation from the database, View Model is a data representation for the page.  Data Model's don't always smoothly fit an application for a View Model, because sometimes you have to alter a data model or combine multiple data models to make a valid View Model to represent the page intent.  Hopefully my change to terminology clarifies for you.

Comment: For readability: In OP's question, `UserModel` is the data model/entity. In this answer, this is now `UserEntity` and `UserModel` is the view model, which OP had called `MyViewModel`.

Comment: Essentially, it sounds like that is pretty much what I was doing. What I think I'm going to do is make sure my entity models are named something like `UserEntity` and then my object models will be `UserModel`. If I need to do something different for the view, I'll create a `UserViewModel` that will do anything specific for that particular view.

Comment: @gin93r Exactly! Sorry if I didn't explain well.

Comment: @Greg You explained perfectly. Thank you :)